# I'm trying to drag a window onto a second monitor while using Team viewer but it just wants to snap to the edge of

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm trying to drag a window onto a second monitor while using Team viewer but it just wants to snap to the edge of the first monitor.Only my cursor move across to the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try the shortcut Windows + Right Arrow key three times.

Comment: Or even better yet, WIN+SHIFT+Right Arrow

Comment: still it only stays on the first monitor

Comment: it doesn't move onto the second monitor

Answer (score 0):

It appears [this has been a known issue since TeamViewer 12.](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/General-Questions/Dragging-windows-between-monitors/td-p/2291) The suggested workaround seems to be dragging the window so that it partially overlaps the second monitor (without moving the mouse across the boundary), then releasing the window, moving the mouse to the second monitor, and then dragging the window to your desired location.

Note this will only work if [the remote host is also configured with multiple screens.](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/General-Questions/Dual-Monitor-support/td-p/6885)